# Decodificar retorno JSON de forma mais rápida

Tags: php

O Sistema captura o endereço do usuário através do CEP, estou utilizando o serviço do [ViaCep](http://viacep.com.br), faço uma validação front-end com o jquery validate e uma back-end com PHP, a validação com jquery pega o endereço do usuário muito rápido e mostra num campo "disabled", já com PHP demora um pouco para processar e isto está deixando o script lento, qual a melhor forma de acelerar a leitura JSON de uma página com PHP?

Exemplo do retorno ViaCep:

```
{
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
}
```

URL:: https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/

No PHP:

```
$cep = 'xxxx';

$cepUrl = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/{$cep}/json/";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cepUrl);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

A partir do JavaScript a conexão se dá via client-side, ou seja, pelo browser. Uma URL, uma vez acessada, tem o conteúdo salvo em cache no computador do usuário.

Em server-side não é salvo esse cache automaticamente quando acessa uma URL. Para otimizar no backend, salve um cache do resultado.

Note também que há outros fatores que influenciam no tempo de resposta como a rede do ambiente, por exemplo, e diversos outros processos no backend.

De uma forma geral, o que pode otimizar muito o processo é salvar um cache do resultado.

Claro que antes disso deve avaliar se é viável salvar o cache. Os dados retornados da URL podem mudar, apesar de que CEP e endereço não mudam tão facilmente, mas não é impossível de acontecer. A decisão fica a critério do seu modelo de negócios.

Chega de bla bla bla e vamos ao que interessa.

Uma otimização, salvando cache dos resultados com PHP:

```
$cep = '01001000';

/*
Local onde será salvo o cache.
É recomendado otimizar com uma melhor organização para evitar ter dezenas de milhares de arquivos numa única pasta. Mas esse não é o foco da questão.
*/    
$file = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cep/'.$cep.'.php';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    /*
    Encontrou um arquivo de cache. O resultado será obtido desse arquivo.
    Esse arquivo já está em formato PHP, portanto, nem precisa converter de json para array do PHP.
    */
    $result = include $file;
} else {

    $cepUrl = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'.$cep.'/json/';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cepUrl);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    /*
    Aqui salvamos o cache já em formato PHP para otimizar também o processo de json_decode().
    Assim não precisará invocar json_decode() sempre que consultar esses dados do cache.
    */
    $content = '<?php'.PHP_EOL.'return array(';
    foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
        $content .= PHP_EOL.'   \''.$k.'\' => \''.$v.'\',';
    }
    $content .= PHP_EOL.');';
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
    unset($file, $content);
}

print_r($result);
```

Na primeira consulta, quando ainda não tem o cache, o processo custa de 1 a 1.8 segundos. Quando a consulta vem do cache o processo custa de 0.0001 a 0.00016 milisegundos.

O exemplo acima é meramente didático. Sugiro que crie algum controle mais sofisticado onde poderá consultar a data em que esse cache foi salvo, por exemplo. Se foi salvo há 6 meses, por exemplo, então force o script a ir buscar os dados online e atualizar o cache. Assim garantirá maior integridade.

No JavaScript pode forçar consultas **sem cache** dessa forma:

```js
    $().ready(function() {
     $("#button").click(function(){
      $("div").html("");
      var d = new Date();
      var n = "?" + d.getTime();
      //n = "";
      console.log(n);
      
      $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/"+n, function(result){
       $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + "<br>");
       });
      });
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="button" id="button" value="request">
    <br>
    <div class="foo"></div>
```

Mesmo consultando sem cache, pelo browser ainda continua com uma boa velocidade de resposta, com um pequeno delay devido a conexão mas obviamente ainda bem mais rápido do que consultar pelo backend sem cache pois há menos processos.

Se você pensar melhor, poderia até descartar o uso do PHP CURL e considerar deixar esse trabalho da consulta para o JavaScript. Mesmo que queira salvar os dados ou acessá-los no backend, poderá então enviar um json para o backend onde salvaria os resultados. Claro que isso não deve estar aberto ao público. Implemente essa lógica somente em ambientes privados onde poderá confiar no usuário.

Enfim, é apenas uma ideia momentânea. Conforme mencionado acima, é possível aprimorar e adaptar conforme as suas necessidades.

Comment: Entendo, já tinha pensando em cache, mas por ser uma consulta tão simples penso que deve ter alguma forma de aprimorar ela, e mesmo com client side sendo rápido, é tão fácil alterar pelo browser e melar todo o back end , agradeço a respota :)

Comment: Não tem mágica. A otimização é por cache. Se espera por alguma técnica mirabolante ou uma função mágica, acredito que não encontrará. Talvez usando `file_get_contents()` pode reduzir alguns milionésimos de segundos em relação ao curl por ser uma função mais leve. Mas não fará diferença significativa. Quando executar algo que traz sempre o mesmo resultado, gere cache pois é redundante executar sempre os mesmos processos para obter o mesmos resultados. Nesse exemplo, a economia de tempo é enorme, de 1 para 0,0001 segundos. É possível melhorar com micro otimizações.

Comment: implementei o cache, a diferença foi gigantesca, obrigado mais uma vez.